# C : convert to integer using bits

Tags: c, bit

C : convert to integer using bits

I need to get integer value from bit arrays of 0, 1.

I want to pass integer arrays and get the decimal number using bit operator.

The following is what I tried but does not work when I tried to pass int arrays, it works with **char* array**. Is there any way that I can pass int arrays and convert it to decimal number? I want to use bit operator.

```
 int toInt(int* bin_arr) {

  int val = 0;
  while (*bin_arr)
   val = (val << 1) | (*bin_arr++ == '1');
  return val;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arithmetic operations are usually used to do what you want. Doing this via bit operations (and bit operations only) is more complicated than it's worth.

Comment: What do mean by "integer arrays"? Do you mean arrays containing only the integers 1 and 0?

Comment: Correction. Just integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop condition assumes that the array is 0-terminated, which is valid for strings, but not integer arrays.  One way to fix this would be to pass a length parameter along with the int pointer, so you know when to stop iterating.

Also, in this expression:

```
(*bin_arr++ == '1')
```

you should remove the single quotes, if you're passing integers rather than characters.

Comment: Thanks, now I have val = (val << 1) | (*bin_arr++ == 1); but the function just returns 1. How do I modify while loop... for(int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) I did this, but seems like returning value regardless of my array, only dependent on initial value of i